# IJCADで現在のレイヤを取得したい

Tags: .net, ijcad

IJCAD2019でVB.net開発をしています。
レイヤを変更して作図するプログラムで、最後に元々選択されていたレイヤに戻したいのですが、選択されているレイヤを示すプロパティがわかりません。
ご教示ください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DatabaseクラスのCLayerプロパティから、現在のレイヤのObjectIdを取得することができます。
また、CLayerプロパティに変更したレイヤのObjectIdを設定することで、現在のレイヤを変更することができます。